# Visualforce page behaves differently in Production than in Sandbox

Tags: visualforce

When in Sandbox and the image is clicked there is a redirect to addApprenticeDetailsAccountLookup and is shown in the section on the opportunity page layout, however when the image is clicked in production the addApprenticeDetails page appears as a full page in the tab.

Controller

```java
public class addApprenticeDetails_CX {

    public String fName { get;set; }
    public String lName { get;set; }
    public String email { get;set; }
    public String accName { get;set; }
    public Id AccId { get;set;}
    public List<Account> accList { get;set;} 
    Public Opportunity currentRecordId { get; set; }

    public addApprenticeDetails_CX(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
       currentRecordId = (Opportunity)controller.getRecord();
    }

    public PageReference callLookup(){
        accList = [Select id,Name from Account];
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/addApprenticeDetailsAccountLookup');
        pr.setRedirect(false);
        return pr;
    }

    public PageReference goBack(){
        accName = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccName');
        AccId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccId');
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/addApprenticeDetails');
        pr.setRedirect(false);
        return pr;
    }

    public PageReference save(){
        if(lName == null || lName == ''){
            ApexPages.addmessage(new 
       ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,
       'Last Name is Required!'));
            return null;
        }
        if(email == null || email == ''){
            ApexPages.addmessage(new 
        ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,
        'Email is Required!'));
            return null;    
        }
        else{
            Contact con = new Contact();

            con.FirstName = fName;
            con.LastName = lName;
            con.Email = email;
            con.AccountId = AccId;
            con.RecordTypeId = 
    Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().
    get('Corporate Contact').getRecordTypeId();
            con.Third_Party_Opportunity__c =  
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
            insert con;


            PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/addApprenticeDetails');
            pr.setRedirect(true);
            return pr;

        }
    }
    public list<Account> accs { get; set; }
    public String searchString { get; set; }
    public addApprenticeDetails_CX(){

    }
    public void search(){
        string searchQuery = 'select name, id from account where name like 
    \'%'+searchString+'%\'Limit 20';
        accs = Database.query(searchQuery);

    }
    public void remove(){
        accs.clear();
    }
}
```

addApprenticeDetails VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" 
extensions="addApprenticeDetails_CX">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction name="callAction" action="{!callLookup}"/>
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:pageMessages />
                <apex:inputText label="First Name" value="{!fName}"/>
                <apex:inputText label="Last Name" value="{!lName}"/>
                <apex:inputText label="Email" value="{!email}"/>
                <apex:inputText label="Lookup Account" style="float:left;" value="{!accName}">
                    <apex:image 
value="https://api.icons8.com/download/
19343120d27c16dd3e9d21ad3aa637f94fd4d5fa/Android_L/PNG/256/
Very_Basic/search-256.png" height="20" onclick="callAction()"/>
                </apex:inputText>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <center>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
            </center>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

addApprenticeDetailsAccountLookup VF page

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" 
extensions="addApprenticeDetails_CX" tabStyle="Contact">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:inputText value="{!searchString}" label="Input"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Search Accounts" action="{!search}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Clear Accounts" action="{!remove}"/>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Search Results">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:repeat value="{!accs}" var="acc">
                    <apex:commandLink value="{!acc.Name}" action="{!goBack}">
                        <apex:param value="{!acc.Name}" name="AccName"/>
<apex:param value="{!acc.Id}" name="AccId"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Is this used as a visualforce "card" inside a Record Detail Page? If so, the setup for the detail page may be different in production than in your sandbox.

Comment: This is in a section on the opportunity page layout. I have checked the configuration of both prod and sandbox and they match. The section is never directed to addApprenticeDetailsAccountlookup page.

Comment: This might be an issue of permissions. Check to see that your production users have permission to access the visualforce pages and controllers.

Comment: I have only made it available for System Admins and they do have access to both the pages and the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with this code is line 
    accList = [Select id,Name from Account];
I have added a limit Too many query rows.